# How to change the innerhtml of <td> inside a <tr> using a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, innerhtml

I have a table with this row: (I have six of this in my table)

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="0">
    <td style="height:20px;" align="left"></td>
    <td style="height:20px;" align="left"></td>
    <td style="height:20px;" align="left"></td>
    <td style="height:20px;" align="left"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to make a loop that will add innerHTML for each td base on the size of the list. So if there are only two box inside the list, only 2 tr will have inner HTML.

```
var y = 0;
<%
ArrayList userBoxList = BoxList.getInstance().getUserBoxList();
for(int x=0; x < userBoxList.size(); x++)
{
    UserBox box = (UserBox) userBoxList.get(x); %>  
    document.getElementById(x).onclick = changeColor;
    document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxNumber()%>";
    document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxName()%>";
    document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxOwner()%>";
    document.getElementById(y).innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxSize()%>";
    y++;

<%}%>
```

Comment: I think you need to edit your question. Its too confusing... The HTML and the Javascript seem unconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fit your requirements. For demonstration see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DfFL/).

**HTML:**

```
<table id="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px;">a</td>
        <td style="height: 20px;">b</td>
        <td style="height: 20px;">c</td>
        <td style="height: 20px;">d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    items[i].innerHTML = items[i].style.height;
}
```

If you would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you could do it like this:

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('td'), function () {
        $(this).html($(this).height());
    });
});
```

Comment: that will only work for the first 4 td...I have multiple 'tr' with 4 'td' each....

Comment: It should work for all <td>-elements, because there are no other specification in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

First of all i recomend you stop using inline styles.
Instead you can add a class to the elements and set the styles to the class in a CSS file.

As far as I understand you want to show inside the table the rows with data:

```
var y = 0, row, cell, data, table = document.getElementById("myTable");
<%
ArrayList userBoxList = BoxList.getInstance().getUserBoxList();
for(int x=0; x < userBoxList.size(); x++)
{
    UserBox box = (UserBox) userBoxList.get(x); %>  
    //Generate an array with all the data to display
    data = ["<%=box.getInfo().getBoxNumber()%>","<%=box.getInfo().getBoxName()%>",
            "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxOwner()%>","<%=box.getInfo().getBoxSize()%>"];
    row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.id = y;
    row.className = "whiteBackground";
    row.onclick = changeColor;

    // Loop through the data and create a cell for each one
    data.forEach(function (dataElement) {
      cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.className = "row20px";
      cell.innerHTML = dataElement;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    // Add the new row to the table
    table.appendChild(row);

    y++;

<%}%>
```